# local.cf spamassassin

Tags: spam-prevention, spam, email-spam, spamassassin

Actually I am trying to write one rule in local.cf spamassassin.
What I need is to block all Viagra emails.

As you know in these emails they write Viagra,VIAGRA,VIAGRA(c) sometimes in the Subject field, sometimes in the Name field, sometime it is the body of the message.

Can you please tell me what will be rule exactly to stop all these emails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can try these kind of simple rules:

```
header   VIAGRA_SUBJECT Subject =~ /viagra/i
header   VIAGRA_FROM    From =~ /viagra/i
meta     VIAGRA_HEADER VIAGRA_FROM && VIAGRA_SUBJECT
score    VIAGRA_HEADER 10.0
describe VIAGRA_HEADER Block Mails with Viagra in subject

body     VIAGRA_BODY /viagra/i
score    VIAGRA_BODY 10.0
describe VIAGRA_BODY Block Mails with Viagra in body
```

Comment: I know this answer is old, but I just wanted to clarify - `VIAGRA_FROM && VIAGRA_SUBJECT` would only match if *both* the `Subject` header and `From` header contained Viagra?  Or am I mis-reading that?

Comment: Yes. The 'meta' defines how rules matches and scores. In this case, it will score only if VIAGRA_SUBJECT & VIAGRA_FROM matches. You could also use meta field using arithmetic, set levels for matching entries, etc. You should consider https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/WritingRules for (a lot) more information.

Answer (score 3):

I have two more to add:

```
body LOCAL_OBFU_VIAGRA /(?:\b[vu]|\B(?:\\\/|\xCE\xBD))[\W_]{0,3}(?:[il1:\|\*\xCC-\xCF\xEC-\xEF\xA6]|\xC4[\xA8-\xB0]|\xC4\xBA|\xC4\xBC|\xC4\xBE|\xC5\x80|\xC5\x82|\xC7[\x8F-\x90]|\xD0[\x86-\x87]|\xD1[\x96-\x97]|\xCE\x8A|\xCE\x90|\xCE\x99|\xCE\xAA|\xCE\xAF|\xCE\xB9|\xCF\x8A)[\W_]{0,3}(?:[a4\*\@\xC0-\xC5\xAA\xE0-\xE5]|\/\\|\xC4[\x80-\x85]|\xC7[\x8D-\x8E]|\xC7[\xBA-\xBB]|\xCE\x86|\xCE\x91|\xCE\x94|\xCE\x9B|\xCE\xAC|\xCE\xB1|\xD0\x90|\xD0\xB0)[\W_]{0,3}(?:[g6]|\xC4[\x9C-\xA3]])[\W_]{0,3}(?:[r\xAE]|\xC5[\x94-\x99]|\xD1\x93)[\W_]{0,3}(?:[a4]\b|(?:[\*\@\xC0-\xC5\xAA\xE0-\xE5]|\/\\|\xC4[\x80-\x85]|\xC7[\x8D-\x8E]|\xC7[\xBA-\xBB]|\xCE\x86|\xCE\x91|\xCE\x94|\xCE\x9B|\xCE\xAC|\xCE\xB1|\xD0\x90|\xD0\xB0)\B)/i
score LOCAL_OBFU_VIAGRA 1.8
describe LOCAL_OBFU_VIAGRA Obfuscated 'VIAGRA' in body
```

The rule above will block obfuscated "Viagra" in the body of the message. The following rule does the same sort of thing but with special characters spelled out:

```
describe MANGLED_VIAGRA mangled viagra
body     MANGLED_VIAGRA /(?!viagra)v{1,3}(?:[_\W]{0,5}|[viagra])[iÌÍÎÏìíîï\|1l\!](?:[_\W]{0,5}|[viagra])[aÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäå4\@](?:[_\W]{0,5}|[viagra])g(?:[_\W]{0,5}|[viagra])r(?:[_\W]{0,5}|[viagra])[aÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäå4\@]/i
score    MANGLED_VIAGRA 2.5
```